# Multiple inheritance of interfaces

Tags: c#, linq, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I was tasked with implementing an interface IPerson and class Person that has the following properties:

```
Title 
Name 
DateOfBirth
Age
```

Implement an interface `IDetails` and class `Details` that inherits from `IPerson` and class `Person` that has these properties:

```
Religion 
National Insurance Number
```

My question is, how can I do multiple inheritance for interfaces? How can IPerson inherit/derive from IDetails?

Comment: public interface IPerson : IDetails { }

Comment: Classes don't inherit from an interface, they simply implement it.

Comment: Can you modify your question so it shows both interfaces IDetails and IPerson and classes Details and Person, since some things are bit vague.

Comment: Perhaps you wrote it just for the sake of the example, but in real world code don't use a property name such as `DoB`. It's quite confusing, go ahead and name it `DateOfBirth` (if that's actually what it means!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically `IDetails` *extends* `IPerson`, but conceptually it's similar to inheriting:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Title {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
    int DoB {get; set;}
    int Age {get; set;}
}

public interface IDetails : IPerson
{
    int Religion {get; set;}
    int NationalInsuranceNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Now any class that *implements* `IDetails` must provide an implementation for all members of `IDetails` *and* `IPerson`.

An example implementation would be:

```
public class PersonWithDetails : IDetails
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int DoB {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    public int Religion {get; set;}
    public int NationalInsuranceNumber {get; set;}

}
```

Note that a class can *implement* multiple interfaces but can only *inherit* from one base class.

Comment: Is interface inheritance constrained by this limitation aswell? Just one dervived base interface?

Comment: No, an interface can extend multiple interfaces.  It gets tricky when you implement them if there are overlapping members, though.  Look at [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) for an example.

Comment: @KirstyWhite Not sure what class you mean, but I added an example implementation

Comment: Class Details, would it just be `public class Details : Person` or `public class Details : IPerson`?

Comment: @KirstyWhite I get the feeling I'm doing your homework for you :).  Try it yourself and add to your question if you get stuck.

Comment: They are not classes. They are interfaces. An interface can "inherit" another interface. Then the sub-interface will have members defined in the super interface. Any class implementing the interface will have to define all the members in it itself.

Comment: @KirstyWhite Keep watching or go back and review interface implementation.  All multiple interfaces means is that one class must provide methods that match the methods/properties of _all_ implemented interfaces.